# what are the branch points of this function $w = \ln(1+\sin(z))?$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

Book says there are infinitely many branch points, but i don't know how to find one. It really confused me.

Comment: Won't they occur where $1+\sin z = 0$ ?

Comment: I am not sure. For example, let z = -π/2, by going around this point 2π, will the value of this function be changed?

Comment: Consider the local linear approximation of $1+\sin z$ near $z_0=-\pi/2$

Comment: It seems the local linear approximation is just 0. Then, ln(0)? But the quadratic approximation is 1/2(z + π/2)^2, it seems working.

Comment: Yes, that's right. For $z=-\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon e^{-i\theta}$, one has $1+\sin z\approx \epsilon^2e^{2i\theta}$. So you can see that if you travel around a small circle centered at $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, the argument of $1+\sin z$ will change by $4\pi$ (note the square).

Comment: Thanks a lot!.........